# How can I extract a string from a line between two different delimeters?

Tags: bash, shell

I need to extract a a string between two delimeters such as ">" & "<", example:  atatata> hello world < agagccac. I need the hello world string stored in a single variable possibly not hello in a[0] and world in a[1]. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose VAR has your required string:
then you can get the required value as:

```
echo $VAR | cut -d '>' -f 2 | cut -d '<' -f 1
```

How it works:

FYI:

for cut :

- -d specifies the delimiter
- -f specifies the field

```
echo $VAR
atatata> hello world < agagccac
```

1. Use cut to get the value after 1st delimiter:

```
VAR1=$(echo $VAR | cut -d '>' -f 2)
echo $VAR1
 hello world < agagccac
```

2. Use cut again to get the value before the ending delimiter

```
VAR2=$(echo $VAR1 | cut -d '<' -f 1)
echo $VAR2
 hello world
```

3. Store the result in some variable:

```
RES=$(echo $VAR | cut -d '>' -f 2 | cut -d '<' -f 1)
echo $RES
 hello world
```